# File Upload input control's onchange event bug in CHROME

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-chrome, onchange

I am having fileupload control having its "multiple" attribute equals to "multiple". I am facing a weird issue in CHROME browser. The isse is that onchange event of file upload control is not firing for more than 12 files selected at once. The event is firing if I have 10 files selected at once. On FF and Safari it is working fine. Here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="alert('');" />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a bug related to the number of caracters in the dialog box : http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44068

Comment: Hi Mat, Thanks for the link. Is there any workaround for this, any solution ?

Comment: Yeah, wait for a bugfix in other version..!

Comment: Man! :) is there any solution for current, as my clients are using multiple file uploader control on chrome ?

Comment: Consider this you have to warn the user or use several single inputs =/